# SSIS SCD wizard does a select * on my data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Visual studio hangs on me when using the Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard.

I select the correct connection.
Then I try to open the dropdown 'Table or view' to select a destination table.
At this moment visual studio hangs on me..

I have this on all client machines and on different visual studio versions and only on this specific database.   In activity monitor I noticed that the wizard does a select * on all tables in the database...   I have one table that has +4billion rows (+300GB). It is the select * on this table that takes so long.

Does anybody have any idea what causes the select * on my database, or why they are doing this? And even better, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the slowly changing dimension wizard in SSIS at all. The data flow it creates performs really badly compared to what you can write with TSQL.

*A couple of assumption*; you need a type 2 SCD and you are using at least SQL Server 2008 with MERGE statements available.

Instead of SSIS use the OUTPUT clause of the MERGE statement within TSQL to perform the dimension update/insert. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Master
SELECT 
    Source_Cust_ID, 
    First_Name, 
    Last_Name, 
    Eff_Date, 
    End_Date, 
    Current_Flag
FROM
    ( 
    MERGE 
        Customer_Master CM
    USING 
        Customer_Source CS
    ON 
        CM.Source_Cust_ID = CS.Source_Cust_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN
        INSERT VALUES 
            (
            CS.Source_Cust_ID, 
            CS.First_Name, 
            CS.Last_Name, 
            CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE()-1, 101),
            '12/31/2199',
            'y'
            )
    WHEN MATCHED 
        AND CM.Current_Flag = 'y'
        AND (CM.Last_Name <> CS.Last_Name )
    THEN
        UPDATE 
        SET 
            CM.Current_Flag = 'n',
            CM.End_date = convert(char(10), getdate()- 2, 101)
    OUTPUT 
        $Action Action_Out,
        CS.Source_Cust_ID,
        CS.First_Name,
        CS.Last_Name,
        convert(char(10), getdate()-1, 101) Eff_Date,
        '12/31/2199' End_Date,
        'y' Current_Flag
    ) AS MERGE_OUT
WHERE 
    MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE';
```

Source: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/11/design-tip-107-using-the-sql-merge-statement-for-slowly-changing-dimension-processing/

Comment: Hey,  Thanks for the answer. For big tables with performance issues this is really really true.  But sometimes 'speed of coding' is more important than 'speed of code' and the wizard will do. Unfortunately the GUI does a select * on all tables and also becomes unusable for small-fast to generate examples.